# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'exact' when run in apache2

Tags: python-3.x, django, apache2.4

I know, similar problems have been posted and discussed here and in other forums. Nonetheless, I was not able to get around the issue.

The follwing code snipped from `File "/data/django/jukeoroni/player/jukeoroni/juke_radio.py"` works just fine in `python manage.py runserver`

```python
    @property
    def last_played(self):
        try:
            return Channel.objects.get(last_played=True)
        except Channel.DoesNotExist:
            LOG.info('no last_played channel, returning None.')
            return None
```

```
[09-12-2021 15:03:49] [INFO] [Dummy-10|2989487200] [player.jukeoroni.jukeoroni]: Button press detected on pin: 16 button: 0X00 (2), label: Play
[09-12-2021 15:03:49] [INFO] [Dummy-10|2989487200] [player.jukeoroni.jukeoroni]: Media inserted: deathmetal (type <class 'player.models.Channel'>)
```

However, the same code results in the titles error when run within `apache2`:

```
[09-12-2021 15:00:32] [INFO] [Dummy-10|2843735072] [player.jukeoroni.jukeoroni]: Button press detected on pin: 16 button: 0X00 (2), label: Play
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/django/jukeoroni/player/jukeoroni/jukeoroni.py", line 813, in _handle_button
    if self.radio.last_played is None:
  File "/data/django/jukeoroni/player/jukeoroni/juke_radio.py", line 126, in last_played
    return Channel.objects.get(last_played=True)
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 424, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 941, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 968, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1393, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1415, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1347, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1187, in build_lookup
    lhs = self.try_transform(lhs, lookup_name)
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1228, in try_transform
    "permitted%s" % (name, output_field.__name__, suggestion)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'exact' for BooleanField or join on the field not permitted, perhaps you meant exact or iexact?
```

`django` (Django 3.2.5) seems to working fine within `apache2` as I can access the `admin` page as well as custom views from all LAN devices. The database is SQLite (default).

`apache2` version:

```bash
[pi@jukeoroni jukeoroni]$ apache2 -version
Server version: Apache/2.4.38 (Raspbian)
Server built:   2021-06-10T10:13:06
```

I wonder where the difference here is coming from and how to solve that problem. Configs? Permissions?

Comment: Related closed [issue #27093](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27093) on Django's issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards that thread. In the meantime, as a test, I switched from `apache2` to `gunicorn` and things work as expected. I think I will go down the `nginx`/`gunicorn` road as I'm not depending on `apache2` at all.